# json_decode retorna null

Tags: php, json, file-get-contents

Tenho um arquivo JSON que está [**nesse link**](http://s.anapro.com.br/a-p/dados/b3gkhu%252f3ohE%253d/estoque.json).
Eu preciso pegar e exibir os dados no PHP, tenho o seguinte código para testar:

```
$linkAnapro = 'http://s.anapro.com.br/a-p/dados/b3gkhu%252f3ohE%253d/estoque.json';

$output = file_get_contents($linkAnapro);
$json = json_decode($output);

print_r($json);
```

O valor que ele me retorna é `NULL`, se faço `print_r($output)` me retorna o JSON. O que pode estar havendo?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A url `http://s.anapro.com.br/a-p/dados/b3gkhu%252f3ohE%253d/estoque.json` está retornando caracteres no conteúdo compatíveis com `iso-8859-1/windows-1252`, para usar o `json_decode` é necessário usar o `utf8_encode` primeiro:

```
<?php
$linkAnapro = 'http://s.anapro.com.br/a-p/dados/b3gkhu%252f3ohE%253d/estoque.json';

$output = file_get_contents($linkAnapro);
$output = utf8_encode($output);
$json = json_decode($output);

print_r($json);
```

> **Nota:** Esta função irá retorna false se o dado codificado `JSON` possui mais que 127 elementos.

Note que o `json_decode` retorna um `stdClass` e que eles ficarão em `utf-8` para converter para `array` use o assim `json_encode(..., true)` e se você for usar `iso-8859-1` (ou compatível) na sua página será necessário uma função recursiva com `utf8_decode` para não aparecer aqueles caracteres "estranhos", segue um exemplo de como fazer:

```
<?php
$linkAnapro = 'http://s.anapro.com.br/a-p/dados/b3gkhu%252f3ohE%253d/estoque.json';

$output = file_get_contents($linkAnapro);
$output = utf8_encode($output);
$json = json_decode($output, true);

function utf8_decode_recursive(&$val, $key){
    $val = utf8_decode($val);
}

array_walk_recursive($json, 'utf8_decode_recursive');

print_r($json);
```

Comment: Obrigado Guilherme, funcionou!

Answer (score 1):

O `json_decode` falha porque o valor que ele recebe contem caracteres *unicode*, provavelmente [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) (**B**yte **O**rder **M**ark).

Uma das formas de contornar isto é usar a função [`utf8_encode`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.utf8-encode.php) antes de chamar [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.json-decode.php).

```php
$linkAnapro = 'http://s.anapro.com.br/a-p/dados/b3gkhu%252f3ohE%253d/estoque.json';
$output = file_get_contents($linkAnapro);

$output = iconv('UTF-8', 'UTF-8//IGNORE', utf8_encode($output));
$json = json_decode($output);

if (json_last_error() == 0) { // Sem erros
    print_r($json);
} else {
    echo "Erro inesperado ". json_last_error();
}
```

A função [`json_last_error()`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.json-last-error.php) neste caso **retorna** `JSON_ERROR_UTF8`, se você preferir tratar este erro ou outros que possam ocorrer, faça o seguinte:

```php
function json_decode2($valor){
$json = json_decode($valor);

switch (json_last_error()) {
    case JSON_ERROR_NONE:
        return $json;
    case JSON_ERROR_DEPTH:
        return 'A profundidade máxima da pilha foi excedida';
    case JSON_ERROR_STATE_MISMATCH:
        return 'JSON inválido ou mal formado';
    case JSON_ERROR_CTRL_CHAR:
        return 'Erro de caractere de controle, possivelmente codificado incorretamente';
    case JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX:
        return 'Erro de sintaxe';
    case JSON_ERROR_UTF8:  // O seu caso!
        $json = iconv('UTF-8', 'UTF-8//IGNORE', utf8_encode($valor));
        return json_encode($json);
    default:
        return 'Erro desconhecido';
    }   
}
```

Para usar:

```php
$linkAnapro = 'http://s.anapro.com.br/a-p/dados/b3gkhu%252f3ohE%253d/estoque.json';
$output = file_get_contents($linkAnapro);

echo json_decode2($output);
```

---

Uma outra forma seria remover os caracteres que estão causando o problema:

```php
$linkAnapro = 'http://s.anapro.com.br/a-p/dados/b3gkhu%252f3ohE%253d/estoque.json';

$output = file_get_contents($linkAnapro);
$json = json_decode(preg_replace('/[\x00-\x1F\x80-\xFF]/', '', $output)); // Remove os caracteres não imprimíveis da string

if (json_last_error() == 0) { // Sem erros
    print_r($json);
} else {
    echo "Erro inesperado ". json_last_error();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No meu caso esse método me ajudou `json_decode(preg_replace('/[\x00-\x1F\x80-\xFF]/', '', $output));`

Comment: Jaime, podes explicar de que maneira a tua resposta ajuda a solucionar a pergunta?

Comment: @Sergio Isso remove caracteres de controle, que não são válidos em JSON.