# json_encode não retorna nada

Tags: php, json

## O que estou fazendo

Estou puxando dados através do PHP com uma lista de cidades para criar um gráfico com o Javascript, e percebi que ele não estava retornando os dados, então eu acessei o arquivo que pega os dados do banco e faz a conversão com o `json_encode` para ver o que acontecia.

## O que aconteceu

O método para obter as cidades está funcionando, e quando dou um `print_r` no resultado ele é mostrado corretamente, mas logo que eu dou um `echo json_encode($resultado)` a página fica vazia.

## Meu código

#### Chamando Método e fazendo parse

```
$result = $cidadeDAO->getCidades();
echo json_encode($result);
```

#### Método para obter cidades

```
public function getCidades() {
        $stmt = self::$connection->prepare("SELECT cidade FROM cd_unidades order by cidade ASC");
        $stmt->execute();
        return $stmt->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }
```

#### Resultado print_r

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [cidade] => Araraquara
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [cidade] => Bauru
        )
)
```

Comment: Deve estar dando algum erro no [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.json-encode.php). Note no manual que ele retorna FALSE caso ocorra algum erro.

Comment: Use a função [`json_last_error`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.json-last-error.php) e verifique qual [valor é retornado](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.json-last-error.php#refsect1-function.json-last-error-returnvalues). Nessa [resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/57178/6454) há um exemplo com `json_decode`, basta adaptá-la para `json_encode`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Experimenta transforma a saída dele:

```
$cidades = array();
while($row = $result->fetch()) {
{
   $cidade = array(
       'cidade' => $row['cidade'],
   );
   array_push($cidades, $cidade);
}
$json = json_encode($cidades);
```

Answer (score 5):

Verifique se os encodings estão corretos, use o utf8_encode para fazer a conversão e testar:

```
$cidades = array();
while($row = $result->fetch()) {
{
   $cidade = array(
       'cidade' => utf8_encode($row['cidade']),
   );
   array_push($cidades, $cidade);
}
$json = json_encode($cidades);
```

> Caso funcione procure verificar no PDO para ele já abrir a conexão em UTF-8

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=myhost;dbname=mydb', 'login', 'password', array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES \'UTF8\''));
```

**Fonte:** http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdo.construct.php

Comment: Me salvando em 2019.

Answer (score -1):

Olá. Gostaria de compartilhar minha solução. Estou usando Yii framework (MVC)

Lá no model onde faz as pesquisa adicionei o código:

```
 return CJSON::encode($this->findHardwareByCategoria(...));
```

E na controller, depois de instanciar o model e armazenar o resultado da função em uma variável, dou um *echo*:

```
echo $minhaVariavel;
return true;
```